# Scaling revenues - Drawbacks and advantages of average vs. median scaling

Tags: scikit-learn, normalization, feature-scaling

**Context**

Currently I am doing some regression-predictions with various machine learning algorithms (still in the experimental phase). Some features I use for the prediction are revenues customers generate. In order to use the revenues properly I have to scale them.

Normally, I have good experiences with `RobustScaling` like *Scikit-learn* provides for *Python* ([documentation here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.RobustScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.RobustScaler)).
Anyhow, this uses the median in order to center the revenues, which is why it is called "robust".

**Question**

Since the median represents an actual number within the dataset I am quite unsure if a median is realy the way to go in order to scale revenue-data.
The revenues contain outliers which makes robust scaling attractive. On the other hand, I have never seen median-aggregations for any money-data. Also, the fact that revenue-data is a floating-point number makes me unsure if the median is what should be applied here.

***What are the drawbacks of applying the median to floating-point numbers like revenues in order to scale them?***

"Drawback" mostly refers to the comparison with using the average.